# Problema con arreglo de personas

Tags: java, array, java-swing

necesito ayuda, estoy empezando con java y estoy realizando una tarea donde tengo que hacer un programa para una compañia de vuelos que registre los datos de los pasajero. La cuestion es que los pasajeros los estoy metiendo en dos arreglos que los tengo definidos en una ventana que es la principal y el arreglo de persona en otra clase donde valido algunos datos pero el problema es que cuando cierro la ventana principal para ocultarla se pierden los datos del arreglo y no se como pasar el arreglo a otra clase o como hacer para que no se me pierdan los datos. Ayuda porfavor. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor agrega tu código como texto